# Returning multiple nodes in cypher with Index lookup

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following cypher query being called multiple times.

```
start n=node:MyIndex(Name="ABC")
return n
```

Then somewhere else in the code

```
start m=node:MyIndex(NAME="XYZ")
return m
```

My data base is hosted in Azure and so I am having latency/performance issues. In order to speed up the process, and to reduce multiple round trips, I thought about combining multiple Cypher queries into a single one.

Actually, I am getting 10+ nodes in lookup but for simplicity I have decided to show example with just two nodes below.

```
start n=node:MyIndex(Name="ABC"), m=node:MyIndex(NAME="XYZ")
return n, m
```

My goal is to get what I can in one round trip instead of 10+. It works successfully if the index lookup on *All* nodes succeeds. However, Cypher query returns zero rows even *if one* index lookup fails. I was hoping that I will get NULL equivalent in n or m on the missing node. However, no luck.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong and any workarounds to reduce the round trips. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parametrized query with [lucene syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Grouping), e.g.:

```
START n=node:MyIndex({query}) return n
```

and parametrize with

```
{'query':'Name:(ABC XYZ)'}
```

where list of names is a string with space separated names you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. That will give me the nodes but it won't help me identify which ones were missing. For instance I will not be able to know if n or m was missing. Secondly, what if I had two different indexes?

Comment: You can find out what names are missing on the client side.

And what do you mean by different indexes? Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: Different indexes could represent nodes of different types.Here is an example. m=node:MyFriendIndex(NAME="XYZ") OR m=node:MyClassmateIndex(NAME="XYZ") etc.

Comment: I think someone's `Friend` and `Classmate`-relationships are better represented within the graph structure. I don't know of a good way to merge index queries where some can result in empty sets.